# Should an <a> tag contain the content it links to

Tags: html, tags, anchor

With `a` tags you can link to content inside the webpage itself, but should you place the content you're linking to inside the `a` tag or outside it?

Like this:

```
<a name="linkToMe"/>
<div id="content">...</div>
```

or like this:

```
<a name="linktoMe">
    <div id="content">...</div>
</a>
```

EDIT:

I dont mean

```
<a href="#id"> <div id="id"> ... </div> </a>
```

My question is:

```
<a href="#id"> Link </a>
...
<a name="id"/>
<div> content </div>
```

or

```
<a href="#id"> Link </a>
...
<div id="id"> content </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is that : when you have a # in the url, the browser takes what is after (an anchor) (for example : test.dev#anchor, it takes anchor) and it scrolls to the element which has the anchor as an id (for example : ....

Therefore, if you want to have a link to a content, you should put it outside :

```
<a href="#anchor">Link !</a>
...
<div id="anchor">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally content your are linking with `a` tag is placed out side the tag. It does not make any sense to place the content within `a` tag which is linking the same content. 
Place the link where ever you want to place it in page, and give id of content as href attribute. like

```
<a href= "#thiscontent"> link</a>
```

then write your else code and place your content according to your design. But give the same id to the content.

```
<div id = "thiscontent">.......</div>
```